# Fetch as google Content-length: 0 when using IIS with active request routing (ARR)

Tags: seo, google, google-search-console, iis

I'm very new to this and just had a new issue dropped on my desk which I could use help with.

Basically all requests for domain name `www.example.com` are routed through an IIS with active request routing (ARR), which then routes the request to the actual hosting server (Azure ARR). The problem is that Fetch as google (Webmaster tools), only the following portion of the page is returned:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Length: 0
Content-Type: text/html
Set-Cookie: ARRAffinity=93d3d6ebca814b60bcbdb0ebaf9bc4abbd10698790d350946ab6503f60b71e05;Path=/;Domain=www.example.com
X-Server: 2
Date: Wed, 15 Mar 2017 12:16:37 GMT
```

When we bypass the IIS with ARR and forward traffic directly to the hosting environment of the www.example.com website, google fetches all the data.

Has anyone encountered similar problem before?